# ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

have an error in compiling a code in oracle, 
the error is ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression,
I want to know how I can solve this problem because 
the function ORDER BY if instead I use GROUP BY and 
SUM do not serve me.

```
SELECT
            INVOICE.CUS_CODE,

            CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE,

            SUM(LINE.LINE_UNITS * LINE.LINE_PRICE )AS "TOTAL PURCHASES"

FROM
            INVOICE, CUSTOMER, LINE

WHERE
            CUSTOMER.CUS_CODE = INVOICE.CUS_CODE  AND INVOICE.INV_NUMBER= LINE.INV_NUMBER

GROUP BY
            INVOICE.CUS_CODE
```

Comment: Why did you think this can be solved without showing your query?

Comment: You really must post your query. There's nothing here to look at.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCE](http://SSCCE.org/) for guidance. "have an error in compiling a code" is meaningless if you don't post your code; how can we possibly tell you how to fix an error in code you don't let us see?

Comment: SORRY THIS THE SQL PROBLEMS

Comment: You must add `CUSTOMER.CUS_BALANCE` to the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by WW, you need to add `CUS_BALANCE` to the group by clause.

Try like this,

```
SELECT invoice.cus_code,
       customer.cus_balance,
       sum(line.line_units * line.line_price )AS "TOTAL PURCHASES"
FROM   invoice, customer, line
WHERE  customer.cus_code = invoice.cus_code  
AND    invoice.inv_number= line.inv_number
GROUP BY invoice.cus_code, customer.cus_balance;
```

Comment: *-or-* remove `customer.cus_balance` expression from the SELECT list, *-or-* wrap the `customer.cus_balance` expression in an aggregate function e.g. `MAX(customer.cus_balance)` *-or-* ... there's more than one solution to the problem.

Comment: @spencer7593, Good points. Thanks. But I think this might be his problem, as he is mention only about doing `SUM` in his question.